# how convert from Extended ASCII to EBCDIC and vice verse when page code is unknow

Tags: java, unix, ascii, extended-ascii, ebcdic

I have two arrays being used for converting from ASCII to EBCDIC and vice verse. The contex is: there is a MyMainframeApp running in UNIX and it only sends/receives files in EBCDIC. Such files have to be read from a MyWebApp in ASCII format, processed, and returned in EBCDIC. The two next arrays satisfy perfectly the convertion. The problem is that now I need to support Extended ASCII (see the last array I got from the internet) so I want join EXTENDED_Array to ASCII[]. What would be the equivalent codes in EBCDIC? The application must run in Windows 2012/JDK 6 and Unix/JDK 6 alike. Is there a safe way to do this if I don't know the page code?
Note: I am not asking how convert from ASCII to EBCDIC (there are good answers for this question in this forum). First, I would like to put in spoot ligh the "EXTENDED" then I am asking what are the equivalent array for the Extended ASCII below and if there is a safe way to work on it when I am not awared about the page code.

```
ASCII[] = {
                0x0020, 0x0021, 0x0022, 0x0023, 0x0024, 0x0025, 0x0026, 0x0027, 0x0028,
                0x0029, 0x002a, 0x002b, 0x002c, 0x002d, 0x002e, 0x002f,
                0x0030, 0x0031, 0x0032, 0x0033, 0x0034, 0x0035, 0x0036, 0x0037, 0x0038,
                0x0039, 0x003a, 0x003b, 0x003c, 0x003d, 0x003e, 0x003f,
                0x0040, 0x0041, 0x0042, 0x0043, 0x0044, 0x0045, 0x0046, 0x0047, 0x0048,
                0x0049, 0x004a, 0x004b, 0x004c, 0x004d, 0x004e, 0x004f,
                0x0050, 0x0051, 0x0052, 0x0053, 0x0054, 0x0055, 0x0056, 0x0057, 0x0058,
                0x0059, 0x005a, 0x005b, 0x005c, 0x005d, 0x005e, 0x005f,
                0x0060, 0x0061, 0x0062, 0x0063, 0x0064, 0x0065, 0x0066, 0x0067, 0x0068,
                0x0069, 0x006a, 0x006b, 0x006c, 0x006d, 0x006e, 0x006f,
                0x0070, 0x0071, 0x0072, 0x0073, 0x0074, 0x0075, 0x0076, 0x0077, 0x0078,
                0x0079, 0x007a, 0x007b, 0x007c, 0x007d, 0x007e
   };

EBCDIC[] = {
                0x0040, 0x005a, 0x007f, 0x007b, 0x005b, 0x006c, 0x0050, 0x007d, 0x004d,
                0x005d, 0x005c, 0x004e, 0x006b, 0x0060, 0x004b, 0x0061,
                0x00f0, 0x00f1, 0x00f2, 0x00f3, 0x00f4, 0x00f5, 0x00f6, 0x00f7, 0x00f8,
                0x00f9, 0x007a, 0x005e, 0x004c, 0x007e, 0x006e, 0x006f,
                0x007c, 0x00c1, 0x00c2, 0x00c3, 0x00c4, 0x00c5, 0x00c6, 0x00c7, 0x00c8,
                0x00c9, 0x00d1, 0x00d2, 0x00d3, 0x00d4, 0x00d5, 0x00d6,
                0x00d7, 0x00d8, 0x00d9, 0x00e2, 0x00e3, 0x00e4, 0x00e5, 0x00e6, 0x00e7,
                0x00e8, 0x00e9, 0x00ad, 0x00e0, 0x00bd, 0x005f, 0x006d,
                0x0079, 0x0081, 0x0082, 0x0083, 0x0084, 0x0085, 0x0086, 0x0087, 0x0088,
                0x0089, 0x0091, 0x0092, 0x0093, 0x0094, 0x0095, 0x0096,
                0x0097, 0x0098, 0x0099, 0x00a2, 0x00a3, 0x00a4, 0x00a5, 0x00a6, 0x00a7,
                0x00a8, 0x00a9, 0x00c0, 0x006a, 0x00d0, 0x00a1
   };

EXTENDED_Array = { 0x00C7, 0x00FC, 0x00E9, 0x00E2,
            0x00E4, 0x00E0, 0x00E5, 0x00E7, 0x00EA, 0x00EB, 0x00E8, 0x00EF,
            0x00EE, 0x00EC, 0x00C4, 0x00C5, 0x00C9, 0x00E6, 0x00C6, 0x00F4,
            0x00F6, 0x00F2, 0x00FB, 0x00F9, 0x00FF, 0x00D6, 0x00DC, 0x00A2,
            0x00A3, 0x00A5, 0x20A7, 0x0192, 0x00E1, 0x00ED, 0x00F3, 0x00FA,
            0x00F1, 0x00D1, 0x00AA, 0x00BA, 0x00BF, 0x2310, 0x00AC, 0x00BD,
            0x00BC, 0x00A1, 0x00AB, 0x00BB, 0x2591, 0x2592, 0x2593, 0x2502,
            0x2524, 0x2561, 0x2562, 0x2556, 0x2555, 0x2563, 0x2551, 0x2557,
            0x255D, 0x255C, 0x255B, 0x2510, 0x2514, 0x2534, 0x252C, 0x251C,
            0x2500, 0x253C, 0x255E, 0x255F, 0x255A, 0x2554, 0x2569, 0x2566,
            0x2560, 0x2550, 0x256C, 0x2567, 0x2568, 0x2564, 0x2565, 0x2559,
            0x2558, 0x2552, 0x2553, 0x256B, 0x256A, 0x2518, 0x250C, 0x2588,
            0x2584, 0x258C, 0x2590, 0x2580, 0x03B1, 0x00DF, 0x0393, 0x03C0,
            0x03A3, 0x03C3, 0x00B5, 0x03C4, 0x03A6, 0x0398, 0x03A9, 0x03B4,
            0x221E, 0x03C6, 0x03B5, 0x2229, 0x2261, 0x00B1, 0x2265, 0x2264,
            0x2320, 0x2321, 0x00F7, 0x2248, 0x00B0, 0x2219, 0x00B7, 0x221A,
            0x207F, 0x00B2, 0x25A0, 0x00A0 };
```

//Example of EBCDIC
J1644€     [1]         [1]1240üÐB„aà[1][1]   [1]1240üÐB„aà[1][1]            890@@0482613                    @1644€ € @  [1]

//I would like to add here the solution I am using and it is working. Although it is not 100% answer to my origin question I hope this can be usefull for future readers. The translation was copied from http://www.flounder.com/ebcdictoascii2.htm

private final int EBCDIC[] = {

```
    0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0x0005, 0x0007, 0x000B, 0x000C, 0x000D, 0x000E, 0x000F

    , 0x0010, 0x0011, 0x0012, 0x0013, 0x0015, 0x0016, 0x0018, 0x0019, 0x001C, 0x001D, 0x001E, 0x001F

    , 0x0022, 0x0025, 0x0026, 0x0027, 0x002D, 0x002E, 0x002F

    , 0x0032, 0x0037, 0x003C, 0x003D, 0x003F

    , 0x0040, 0x0042, 0x0043, 0x0044, 0x0045, 0x0046, 0x0047, 0x0048, 0x0049, 0x004A, 0x004B, 0x004C, 0x004D, 0x004E, 0x004F

    , 0x0050, 0x0051, 0x0052, 0x0053, 0x0054, 0x0055, 0x0056, 0x0057, 0x0058, 0x0059, 0x005A, 0x005B, 0x005C, 0x005D, 0x005E, 0x005F

    , 0x0060, 0x0061, 0x0062, 0x0063, 0x0064, 0x0065, 0x0066, 0x0067, 0x0068, 0x0069, 0x006A, 0x006B, 0x006C, 0x006D, 0x006E, 0x006F

    , 0x0070, 0x0071, 0x0072, 0x0073, 0x0074, 0x0075, 0x0076, 0x0077, 0x0078, 0x0079, 0x007A, 0x007B, 0x007C, 0x007D, 0x007E, 0x007F

    , 0x0080, 0x0081, 0x0082, 0x0083, 0x0084, 0x0085, 0x0086, 0x0087, 0x0088, 0x0089, 0x008A, 0x008B, 0x008C, 0x008D, 0x008E, 0x008F

    , 0x0090, 0x0091, 0x0092, 0x0093, 0x0094, 0x0095, 0x0096, 0x0097, 0x0098, 0x0099, 0x009A, 0x009B, 0x009C, 0x009D, 0x009E, 0x009F

    , 0x00A0, 0x00A1, 0x00A2, 0x00A3, 0x00A4, 0x00A5, 0x00A6, 0x00A7, 0x00A8, 0x00A9, 0x00AA, 0x00AB, 0x00AC, 0x00AD, 0x00AE, 0x00AF

    , 0x00B0, 0x00B1, 0x00B2, 0x00B3, 0x00B4, 0x00B5, 0x00B6, 0x00B7, 0x00B8, 0x00B9, 0x00BA, 0x00BB, 0x00BC, 0x00BD, 0x00BE, 0x00BF

    , 0x00C0, 0x00C1, 0x00C2, 0x00C3, 0x00C4, 0x00C5, 0x00C6, 0x00C7, 0x00C8, 0x00C9, 0x00CA, 0x00CB, 0x00CC, 0x00CD, 0x00CE, 0x00CF

    , 0x00D0, 0x00D1, 0x00D2, 0x00D3, 0x00D4, 0x00D5, 0x00D6, 0x00D7, 0x00D8, 0x00D9, 0x00DA, 0x00DB, 0x00DC, 0x00DD, 0x00DE, 0x00DF

    , 0x00E0, 0x00E1, 0x00E2, 0x00E3, 0x00E4, 0x00E5, 0x00E6, 0x00E7, 0x00E8, 0x00E9, 0x00EA, 0x00EB, 0x00EC, 0x00ED, 0x00EE, 0x00EF

    , 0x00F0, 0x00F1, 0x00F2, 0x00F3, 0x00F4, 0x00F5, 0x00F6, 0x00F7, 0x00F8, 0x00F9, 0x00FA, 0x00FB, 0x00FC, 0x00FD, 0x00FE

    };
```

private final int ASCII[] = {

```
    0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0x0009, 0x007F, 0x000B, 0x000C, 0x000D, 0x000E, 0x000F

    , 0x0010, 0x0011, 0x0012, 0x0013, 0x000A, 0x000B, 0x0018, 0x0019, 0x001C, 0x001D, 0x001E, 0x001F

    , 0x001C, 0x000A, 0x0017, 0x001B, 0x0005, 0x0006, 0x0007

    , 0x0016, 0x0004, 0x0014, 0x0015, 0x001A

    , 0x0020, 0x00E2, 0x00E4, 0x00E0, 0x00E1, 0x00E3, 0x00E5, 0x00E7, 0x00F0, 0x00A2, 0x002E, 0x003C, 0x0028, 0x002B, 0x007C

    , 0x0026, 0x00E9, 0x00EA, 0x00EB, 0x00E8, 0x00ED, 0x00EE, 0x00EF, 0x00EC, 0x00DF, 0x0021, 0x0024, 0x002A, 0x0029, 0x003B, 0x005E

    , 0x002D, 0x002F, 0x00C2, 0x00C4, 0x00C0, 0x00C1, 0x00C3, 0x00C5, 0x00C7, 0x00D1, 0x00A6, 0x002C, 0x0025, 0x005F, 0x003E, 0x003F

    , 0x00F8, 0x00C9, 0x00CA, 0x00CB, 0x00C8, 0x00CD, 0x00CE, 0x00CF, 0x00CC, 0x005F, 0x003A, 0x0023, 0x0040, 0x0027, 0x003D, 0x0022

    , 0x00D8, 0x0061, 0x0062, 0x0063, 0x0064, 0x0065, 0x0066, 0x0067, 0x0068, 0x0069, 0x00AB, 0x00BB, 0x00F0, 0x000D, 0x00DE, 0x00B1

    , 0x00B0, 0x006A, 0x006B, 0x006C, 0x006D, 0x006E, 0x006F, 0x0070, 0x0071, 0x0072, 0x00AA, 0x00BA, 0x00E6, 0x00B8, 0x00C6, 0x00A4

    , 0x00B5, 0x007E, 0x0073, 0x0074, 0x0075, 0x0076, 0x0077, 0x0078, 0x0079, 0x007A, 0x00A1, 0x00BF, 0x00D0, 0x005B, 0x00FE, 0x00AE

    , 0x00AC, 0x00A3, 0x00A5, 0x0095, 0x00A9, 0x00A7, 0x00B6, 0x00BC, 0x00BD, 0x00BE, 0x00DD, 0x00A8, 0x00AF, 0x005D, 0x0092, 0x00D7

    , 0x007B, 0x0041, 0x0042, 0x0043, 0x0044, 0x0045, 0x0046, 0x0047, 0x0048, 0x0049, 0x009B, 0x00F4, 0x00F6, 0x00F2, 0x00F3, 0x00F5

    , 0x007D, 0x004A, 0x004B, 0x004C, 0x004D, 0x004E, 0x004F, 0x0050, 0x0051, 0x0052, 0x00B9, 0x00FB, 0x00FC, 0x00F9, 0x00FA, 0x00FF

    , 0x005C, 0x00F7, 0x0053, 0x0054, 0x0055, 0x0056, 0x0057, 0x0058, 0x0059, 0x005A, 0x00B2, 0x00D4, 0x00D6, 0x00D2, 0x00D3, 0x00D5

    , 0x0030, 0x0031, 0x0032, 0x0033, 0x0034, 0x0035, 0x0036, 0x0037, 0x0038, 0x0039, 0x00B3, 0x00DB, 0x00DC, 0x00D9, 0x00DA

    };
```

Comment: Won't most -- if not outright *all*! -- of the Extended ASCII codes simply not be available in EBCDIC?

Comment: If you know how to convert from/to ASCII/EBCDIC, why don't you use that to generate a lookup table?

Comment: You realize that there are several EBDIC charsets already bult into the JDKS?

Comment: Is there really such a thing as *extended ASCII*; are you actually confusing it for some other character encoding?

Comment: Firstly, thank you all of you. I added a EBCDIC snippet to exemplify what I will receive from mainframe side. If you look above you will see an array named EXTENDED_Array but I don't know the equivalent of this Array in EBCDIC. How can I discover each one to match with according to its code page? For instance, let me assume that I have two servers:one is UTF-8 and other is ISO-8859. Look at the first char from EXTENDED_Array 0x00C7. What is the equivalent in EBDIC in UTF-8 and which is equivalent in ISO-8859? How do I discover that so I can complete the EBDIC[] array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safely, you can't when the codepage is unknown. Your best bet is

1. Custom conversion tables
2. Sniffing to try to guess the codepage

Comment: About your second comment, is there a way to figure out what is the codepage in the server from Java? I mean, in run time, check what is the codepage and if it is abc I do certain logic or if it is def I do other flow. What exactly you mean by "sniffing" to guess the code page? Can you point some example? Honestly, I have been using this term to apply to http comunication but I believe you want to say other thing.

Comment: Bad word choice. I was thinking of reading the first few bytes of the content (1024 or something like that) and the use jchardet or something similar to get a guesstimate on the codepage

Comment: Do you know if it is safe to use jchardet to figure out exactly the codepage? I read http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/ and it seems quite simple to use but I am wondering if I can rely on it. The same application will be running in Windows 2012 and Mainframe/Unix where I don't have control on.

Comment: You can never be sure for an external piece of code. It works pretty well, but you'll have to test it in your data. What I'd do is create a small corpus of files with known codepages and cross-check it with that jchardet would give you. This could give you a good estimation on how much you can trust it.

Comment: I added above the solution I am using in order to be usefull for future readers. Thanks to everybody!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the mainframe ?